# Find the values of $x$ which makes $\det (A)=0$ without expending determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Find the values of $x$ which makes $\det(A)=0$ without expending determinant: Let $A$ :
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & x \\2 & 1 & x^2\\ 4 & -1 & x^3  \end{bmatrix} $$

How can I solve this?

Comment: x=0, -1 or 2 are obvious solutions, no?

Comment: I have to write it formally. I can not say it is obvious.

Comment: If the determinant is zero that means the matrix is not invertible. If the matrix is not invertible then it must have at least one linearly dependent column. You can think about which values of $x$ creates dependence among the columns.

Comment: Also note that $\det A=0$ is a polynomial equation of degree $3$ in this case, thus it has exactly $3$ (not necessary different) solutions over $\mathbb C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The determinant of a matrix is $0$ if and only if its rows are not linearly independent. So, you need to find $x$ so that there is no non-trivial solution the system of equations
$$
a\langle1,-1,x\rangle+b\langle2,1,x^2\rangle+c\langle4,-1,x^3\rangle=\langle0,0,0\rangle.
$$
(Note that you could also use the column space for this; however, I think that the solution will be faster this way.)

Based on the first and second coordinates, you can get necessary conditions on $a,b,c$ in order for there to be solutions; then leverage this to find information about $x$.

Answer (score 5):

Solution. $x=0$ or $-1$ or $2$ - The determinant of a Vandermonde matrix $A=(a_j^{i})$ vanishes iff $a_j=a_k$, for some $j\ne k$. So the first columns are powers of $2$, the second, powers of $-1$, and clearly, for $x=0$, vanishes the third colunm.

Comment: It's a Vandermonde *multiple*  $\,(\color{#0a0}{-1})\color{#c00}x\, V(2,\color{#0a0}{-1},\color{#c00}x),\,$ which explains the root $\,x = 0.\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

For example, if x=-1 det(A)=0, because the 2nd and 3d columns will be the same.

Comment: It is not a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from definition (or from Laplace expansion) you can see that this determinant is a polynomial of degree (at most) 3 in variable $x$.

If you know 3 roots of this polynomial (and the roots $x=0,-1,2$ are relatively easy to guess), then you know that there are no other solutions. (Third degree polynomial can have at most 3 real roots.)